# Unix ls command file name sort (differently than default)

Tags: bash, sorting, ls

```
Chris-Muenchs-Mac-Book-Pro:database cmuench$ ls -1
database.sql
database_10.0-10.1.sql
database_10.1-10.2.sql
database_10.3-10.4.sql
database_10.4-10.5.sql
database_10.5-10.6.sql
database_10.9-11.0.sql
database_11.0-11.1.sql
database_11.1-11.2.sql
database_11.2-11.3.sql
database_11.6-12.0.sql
database_12.1-12.2.sql
database_12.11-12.12.sql
database_12.12-12.13.sql
database_12.13-12.14.sql
database_12.3-12.4.sql
database_12.4-12.5.sql
database_12.5-12.6.sql
database_12.9-12.10.sql
```

Is there a way to sort like this?

```
database.sql
database_10.0-10.1.sql
database_10.1-10.2.sql
database_10.3-10.4.sql
database_10.4-10.5.sql
database_10.5-10.6.sql
database_10.9-11.0.sql
database_11.0-11.1.sql
database_11.1-11.2.sql
database_11.2-11.3.sql
database_11.6-12.0.sql
database_12.1-12.2.sql
database_12.3-12.4.sql
database_12.4-12.5.sql
database_12.5-12.6.sql
database_12.9-12.10.sql
database_12.11-12.12.sql
database_12.12-12.13.sql
database_12.13-12.14.sql
```

I am on Mac OS X and don't have the sort -V option

Comment: Not programming-related - try http://superuser.com or http://apple.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Upvoting because this question can simply be tagged as 'bash' and then become 'programming related'

Answer (score 1):

You can probably sort by time using `ls -lrt` or some combination like that

`r` for reverse,
`t` for time

Comment: Hummm... And how does the output look?

Comment: all out of order, I think using git causes filename save times to get modified.

Comment: @ChrisMuench I'm sorry dude, I ran out of ideas. :(

Comment: No problem, I don't think this is easily solvable, thanks for trying

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [sort utility](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20030724161328982):

```
ls | sort -n
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Mac OS, but give this a try:

```
 LC_COLLATE=C ls -1
```

Comment: Easily testable for anyone:  1) copy list of filenames above.  2) paste into text file 'filenames'.  3) `for x in \`cat filenames\`; do touch $x; done`  4) Try the command above